# Program terminates before reading all struct members

Tags: c++, string, struct

The following is the code. It contains a struct **student** with int **rno** and string **name** as members. I use a loop to read the members of all student variables. But the program terminates as soon as i enter any letter. Also, the string entered is not displayed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    struct student {
        int rno;
        string name;
    };

    student s[4];

    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        cin >> s[i].rno;
        getline( cin, s[i].name );
    }

    string line = "";
    for( i = 0; i < 80; ++i) line += '-';

    cout << line << "ROLL\tNAME\n" << line << '\n';

    for( i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        cout << s[i].rno << '\t' << s[i].name << '\n';
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: seems to be working fine for me, did you try to run it with valgrind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is using the `>>` stream operator and then using `getline` without flushing the stream of any unwanted new line characters.

Then when you read in the next struct you'll have the string you wanted to be the previous elements name and your stream will likely fail to read in an integer (unless the name started with a number).

So your read in loop should use `cin.ignore(MAX_INT,'\n')` or instead of `MAX_INT` some value longer than any line you would expect.

`cin.ignore` will ignore the next X characters or until it reaches the specified character (in this case `MAX_INT` character or until it reaches the newline character `'\n'`).

Your read in for loop would then look like:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
    cin >> s[i].rno;
    cin.ignore(MAX_INT, '\n');
    getline(cin, s[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! max_int should be greater than no of digits in rno right? ie it should be greater than no. of characters input earlier?

Comment: Yeah, I just use MAX_INT if it's defined on the system i'm using. I'm not sure if all systems have it defined. But you could also use the numeric_limits in the standard library if needed.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `cin.ignore()` after get an *int* type and before get *char* type

and for getting `char` array it's better to use `gets()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct student {
    int rno;
    string name;
};

int main() {
    student s[4];
    int i;
    for( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i) {
        cin >> s[i].rno;
        cin.ignore();
        gets(s[i].name);
    }
    string line = "";
    for( i = 0 ; i < 80 ; ++i) line += '-';
    cout << line << "ROLL\tNAME\n" << line << '\n';
    for( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i)
        cout << s[i].rno << '\t' << s[i].name << '\n';
}
```

`cin` leaves the newline character in the stream. Adding `cin.ignore()` to the next line clears/ignores the newline from the stream.
This is used mainly with combinations of cin and getline.

see [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475384/when-and-why-do-i-need-to-use-cin-ignore-in-c) too

Comment: Thank you that solved it! However, what was really happening? why was enter terminating the program

Comment: why do we need `gets` instead `getline`?

Comment: answer modified for describe  @Tim

Comment: i think it's simple and easy to understand for newbie users @Steephen `gets() - gets_s() - puts()` instead of advance functions like `getline()`

Comment: @ArashHatami http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873401/difference-between-cin-get-and-cin-getline

Comment: `gets` doesn't take `std::string` as an argument and was deprecated in C++11