# Ifstream.get reads only first line

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have the following program

```
ifstream input;
input.open("File.txt",ios::in);
while(input){
    char arr[30];
    input.get(arr,30);
    cout << arr;
}
```

My file is

```
A 100
B 200
```

However, my output has only the first line, that is `A 100`. When I replace `.get` with `.getline` it works as expected.

I did some [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873401/difference-between-cin-get-and-cin-getline) and found that `.get` keeps the `\n` in the stream, while `.getline` removes it altogether.

Is that the reason why I'm getting only the first line? If it is, how do I fix it?

Comment: "When I replace .get with .getline it works as expected." - so why not use getline? And why not use std::string?

Comment: @NeilButterworth School uses an outdated version of C++ :-(

Comment: Is your school still using some 20-year-old compiler like Turbo C++? `std::istream::getline` and `std::string` have always been part of standard C++ since C++98.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang Unfortunately, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. You found already the problem. After "A 100" has been read, the '\n' will still be in the stream. The next get will again not read the '\n' and return an empty string. And again and again. So this will never work.

You coud use `std::ignore` or `ifstream::getline`.

However, I would recomend none. Reason: You should not, never and never ever use C-Style arays like `char arr[30];` in C++. Never.

Simply use a `std:::string`.

See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::ifstream input{ "r:\\File.txt" };
    std::string line{};
    while (std::getline(input,line)) {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```