# difference between input using ignore and so on

Tags: c++

I wanted to clear some doubt regarding the function

```
cin.ignore(1,'\n');
```

code:

```
char x[80];      
cin>>x;       
cin.ignore(1,'\n');
```

If user input the word:    paul Smith
does the program looks for the first space in the word and ignores/delete the rest of the characters?
Hence the program takes paul only and discards Smith?
Am I right?
I'm getting confused! Please explain in really simple words because I cannot understand the explanation on google regarding this issue.

Comment: Useful information to study:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io

Comment: possible duplicate of [When and why do I need to use cin.ignore() in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475384/when-and-why-do-i-need-to-use-cin-ignore-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cin.ignore(1,'\n');
```

is not very useful. It will ignore only one character.

```
cin.ignore(100,'\n');
```

will ignore up to 100 characters but will stop after it encounters a `'\n'`.

In your case,

```
cin>>x;
```

will read `paul` into `x`. The line

```
cin.ignore(1,'\n');
```

will consume the space after `paul`. Hence, `Smith` will be left on the input stream.

> Hence the program takes paul only and discards Smith?

No. I hope that is clear from the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> x;
```

Since `x` is a string or `char` array, this reads one word (everything up to the first whitespace character) from the input, and stores it in `x`.

```
cin.ignore(1, '\n');
```

reads and ignores one character from the input. It won't read the whole rest of the line. More generally:

```
cin.ignore(n, delim);
```

reads and ignores characters until it has either read `n` characters or reached a character equal to `delim`. If you want to ignore until the end of the line, no matter how many characters that is, do:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```