# How do I get user inputs for a string and then an int?

Tags: c++, string, std, user-input, getline

I have a database class that is an array that will hold a number of objects.
The function will take a couple of inputs from the user which include both strings and ints

For example:

```
std::cout << "Enter first name: ";
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
std::getline(std::cin, first_name);
std::cout << "Enter last name: ";
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
std::getline(std::cin, last_name);
std::cout << "Enter age: ";
std::cin >> age;
```

When I run the code, after I hit enter after entering the last name, it just starts a new line and I have to enter another input before it asks for the age input.

I heard it was bad to mix getline and cin, and that it's better to use one or the other. What can I do to make this work and what would be good practice moving forward?

Edit: I added in the ignores when I initially searched for solutions because without them, the code wouldn't bother waiting for user input. The output would be "Enter first name: Enter last name: "

Edit2: RESOLVED. Problem was I had used "cin >>" earlier in my code for user to input an int variable and needed the first cin.ignore statement, but not the other. Did not include that part of the code because I didn't know that was affecting it. Still new to all this so thanks everyone for their help!

Comment: Remove the `ignore` lines because `std::getline()` already moves you to the next line.

Comment: It's bad not to know what you're doing. What's with the `ignore`s?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you ignoring the input before the `getline`?  Looks like your forcing the User to enter a blank line before the program inputs the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`std::basic_istream::ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), this function behaves as an **Unformatted Input Function** which mean it is going to **block** and wait for user input if there is nothing to skip in the buffer.

In your case both of your `ignore` statments are not neccessary since `std::getline()` will not leave the new line character in the buffer. So what is actually happening is:

```
std::cout << "Enter first name: ";
/*your first input is skipped by the next ignore line because its going to block until
input is provided since there is nothing to skip in the buffer*/
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
/* the next getline waits for input, reads a line from the buffer and also removes the 
new line character from the buffer*/
std::getline(std::cin, first_name);

std::cout << "Enter last name: ";
/*your second input is skipped by the next ignore line because its going to block until
input is provided since there is nothing to skip in the buffer*/
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
/* the next getline waits for input and this is why it seems you need to provide 
another input before it ask you to enter the age*/
std::getline(std::cin, last_name);
```

You need to remove the `ignore` statments to make this work. You may also want to read [*When and why do I need to use cin.ignore() in C++*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475384/when-and-why-do-i-need-to-use-cin-ignore-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Your `std::cin::ignore` calls are not helping you. They are only needed after an input that does not extract the *end-of-line* character (`>>`).

```
std::string first_name;
std::string last_name;
int age;

std::cout << "Enter first name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, first_name); // end of line is removed

std::cout << "Enter last name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, last_name); // end of line is removed

std::cout << "Enter age: ";
std::cin >> age; // doesn't remove end of line
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // this does
// input can proceed as normal
```

You only need the `std::cin::ignore` call after `std::cin >> age;` because that doesn't remove the end of line character whereas the `std::getline` calls do.

Comment: When I remove the ignore lines, the output in console goes straight from "Enter first name: " to "Enter last name: ", so output reads "Enter first name: Enter last name: " before allowing user input

Comment: @ptu27 Do you have other code performing input operation before the one you showed?

Comment: @bkVnet Yea. I have a user input for an int. Program outputs a list of options and user will input an int to select which option via std::cin

Comment: @put27 That is why, if you used the extraction `operator>>`,like `cin>>x`, before using `getline` then you need to call `ignore`. So leave the first `ignore` and remove the other.

Comment: @bkVnet Thank you!! Just did that and it fixed it. Also fixed the same problem I was having elsewhere in the code. Only started teaching myself 2 weeks ago so everything is still new to me.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing the `ignore` function calls:

```
std::string name;
std::cout << "Enter name: ";
std::getline(cin, name);
unsigned int age;
std::cout << "Enter age: ";
std::cin >> age;
```

Comment: I didn't have ignore lines initially, but I kept getting the output: "Enter first name: Enter last name: ". I looked around for some solutions and that's what I came across.