# istringstream ignores first letter

Tags: c++, istringstream

I am trying to access different words in a string using `std::istringstream` and I am also doing so with multiple test cases.

```
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
     string arr;
     cin.ignore();
     getline(cin,arr);
     istringstream iss(arr);
     string word;
     while(iss>>word)
     {
          cout<<word;
      }
 }
```

For the first test case, everything is perfect (i.e. it outputs the correct words). But for every subsequent test case, the first letter of the first word is left out.

Example:

> Input:
>
> ---
>
> 4
>
> hey there hey
>
> hi hi hi
>
> my name is xyz
>
> girl eats banana

And I'm getting:

> Output:
>
> ---
>
> hey there hey
>
> i hi hi
>
> y name is xyz
>
> irl eats banana

Can anyone please suggest me what to do and why is this error occurring?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] please. What is `arr` actually?

Comment: Yes I did, Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Comment: Move `cin.ignore()` before the loop. Also try to figure out what it actually does,

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that formatted input, i.e., something like `in >> value` conventionally skips leading whitespace before attempting to read. Unformatted input, on the other hand, doesn't skip leading whitespace. With the `std::cin.ignore();` in your loop you make the assumption that `std::getline(std::cin, arr)` would leave the newline in the input like the input of `t` does. That is not so. `std::getline()` extracts and stores all characters up to the first newline where it stop, still extracting the newline. So, you'd remove the `cin.ignore();` from the loop.

The key question becomes how to switch between formatted input and unformatted input. Since the newline upon entry of a numeric value may be preceded with arbitrary spaces which you probably also want to ignore, there are essentially to ways:

1. `std::cin >> std::ws;` skips all leading whitespace. That may include multiple newlines and spaces at the beginning of the line. Skipping those may not necessarily desirable.
2. `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` ignores all characters up to and including the first newline. That would allow for empty lines to follow up as well as lines starting with leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

This line is the culprit: `cin.ignore();`.

When [`std::basic_istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is called without any arguments, it ignores exactly 1 character.

In your case, `std::cin.ignore()` will ignore the first letter, but not for the first test case, because at that point `std::cin` is empty, so there is nothing to ignore. But then, `std::cin` has the other words in it, so it ignores 1 character from the first word.

Comment: I think in the first case there is something to ignore,i.e the new line character, but the next time the user input will already have been skipped one character by the time it gets to the `getline` statement.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [`std::basic_istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

> Extracts and discards characters from the input stream until and
>   including delim. **ignore behaves as an UnformattedInputFunction**

Its worth to mention that `std::basic_istream::ignore` will **block and wait for user input** if there is **nothing** to ignore in the stream.

With this in mind, lets break down what your code does:

1. the first time you call this function in your loop, it is going to
   ignore the new line character that is still in the buffer from the
   previous `cin>>t` operation. Then the `getline` statment will wait and read a line from the user.
2. The next time around, since there is nothing in the buffer to
   ignore(as `std::getline` doesn't leave the new line character in the
   buffer), it is going to **block and wait for input** to ignore. So
   the next time the program block and waits for input, it is because
   of the `ignore()` function,not the `getline` function as you would
   have hoped, and the moment you provide an input(i.e you second test
   case),one character from the input is going to be ignored.
3. The next `getline` function will not block since there is something
   in the buffer left by the previous `ignore` function after it
   ignores the first character of the input so `getline` will read the
   remaining string which will happen to be one character short.
4. The process continues from step 2 until your loop terminates.

---

```
int t;
cin>>t;//this leaves new line character in the buffer
while(t--)
{
    string arr;
    cin.ignore();//this will ignore one character from the buffer,so the first time 
                //it will ignore the new line character from the previous cin input
               //but next time it will block and wait for input to ignore
    getline(cin,arr);//this will not block if there is something in the buffer 
                    //to read
     ...
}
```

The solution would be to move the `ignore` statement out of the loop and next to your `cin>>t` statement. It's also better write `ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');` in this case. You might also want to read [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475384/when-and-why-do-i-need-to-use-cin-ignore-in-c) to see when and how to use `ignore`.