# c++ hangs when cin double but proceeds if entering an integer

Tags: c++

I have a program that needs to read 3 attributes from the user. It can read the first 2 just fine, when it tries to read the 3rd attribute (a double) it freezes until you enter an integer.

Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#include <string>
#include "book.h"


Book::Book(const std::string &serialNo, const std::string &title, double price) : serialNo(serialNo), title(title),
                                                                                  price(price) {}
const std::string &Book::getSerialNo() const {
    return serialNo;
}

void Book::setSerialNo(const std::string &serialNo) {
    Book::serialNo = serialNo;
}

const std::string &Book::getTitle() const {
    return title;
}

void Book::setTitle(const std::string &title) {
    Book::title = title;
}

double Book::getPrice() const {
    double scale = .1;
    return (int)(price / scale) * scale;
}

void Book::setPrice(double price) {
    Book::price = price;
}


map<string, Book *> addNewBook(map<string, Book *> inventory) {
    printf("**Add New Book**\n\nNote: Type quit and enter on the serial no. to return to the Main Menu\n");
    string serialNo, title;
    double price;
    while(serialNo != "quit") {
        printf("Serial No.:");
        cin >> serialNo;
        if (serialNo == "quit") {
            continue;
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        printf("\nTitle: ");
        getline(cin, title);
        printf("\nPrice: ");
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cin >> price;
        if (inventory.find(serialNo) == inventory.end()) {
            inventory[serialNo] = new Book(serialNo, title, price);
        } else {
            printf("Serial No. exist already, please enter again:\n");
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    }
    return inventory;
}

int main() {
    map<string, Book*> inventory;
    addNewBook(inventory);
}
```

If you enter some string for the first 2 inputs, and something like 2.5 for the 3rd it will hang until you enter something like 12.

How do I prevent the hang and have it read the 2.5?

Comment: When you call `addNewBook(inventory);`, do you forget that the function has a return value?

Comment: Not in my actual project, this is just a contrived example. In my actual project I do inventory = addNewBook(inventory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and why do I need to use cin.ignore() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475384/when-and-why-do-i-need-to-use-cin-ignore-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure what the actual error is, but to solve your problem, I just removed the second and third `cin.clear()`/`cin.ignore()`, and your code works. I believe the problem may lie with you ignoring the third input, so that that you have to reenter the price. You don't even need the second and third `cin.ignore()`, since `getline()` is before both ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191428/6525260)). Here is a working [repl](https://repl.it/repls/CarelessImpoliteDavidstiger).

Answer (score 0):

The combo

```
cin >> serialNo;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
```

is used to eat the newline character left in the input buffer by `operator>>`. This is done so that a `getline` following it will not treat the buffer as empty-line+`\n`.

However, `getline` is different in that it *does* consume the `\n` at the end when reading a whole line, and leaves nothing in the input buffer.

So now

```
getline(cin, title);
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
```

expects one `'\n'`for the `getline` and *another one* for the `ignore`.

That's why you have to type *anything*+enter to continue.