# If statements in a do while loop with a yes or no ending

Tags: c++, if-statement, do-while

I am new to coding and I'm trying to do a long `do while` loop with nested `if` statements but I'm having issues with getting my loop to actually loop.

Instead of getting help directly on my project, which has a very long code, I made a simple kind of like it version. It also does not loop.  It will get to the end and ask the user if they want to try again but when "y" is entered it ignores the if statements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sodaChoice;
    char answer = 'n';

    do
    {
        cout << "Please choose your favorite soda from the following: Rootbeer, Diet Coke, Coke, Sprite" << "\n";
        getline(cin, sodaChoice);

        if (sodaChoice == "Rootbeer")
        {
            cout << "Me too!" << "\n";
        }
        else if (sodaChoice == "Diet")
        {
            cout << "Not me :(" << "\n";
        }
        else if (sodaChoice == "Coke")
        {
            cout << "It's alright" << "\n";
        }
        else if (sodaChoice == "Sprite")
        {
            cout << "only if I'm sick" << "\n";

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "That was not on the list";
        }
        cout << "would you like to try again?";
        cin >> answer;



    } while (answer == 'y'|| answer == 'Y');




    return 0;
}
```

I thought maybe I needed a do loop in the do loop around the if statements but then I didn't know how to go about it.  Any help would be appreciated. I have spent many, many hours trying to figure it out.

I tried to ask my teacher, but my college teaches from some generic curriculum that their dean wrote based on her book. He is not very enthusiastic about helping or teaching.

EDIT:
Thank you all for the answers! As for this being a duplicate question, I haven't learned cin.ignore yet, so I wasn't aware that it was relevant to my issue.  Thank you all for teaching me!

Comment: I like how my pleasant thank you & congratulations to the OP for their MCVE was deleted. Guess it violated the code of conduct.

Comment: @user202729 It's impossible to know when comments are read and thus no longer needed. Rushing to delete harmless comments after just a few hours (max) is harmful.

Comment: @user202729 Oh I have, long ago. It's a lost cause!

Answer (score 13):

With

```
cin >> answer;
```

you read exactly *one* character. The problem is that you entered at least *two* characters when writing the answer. The actual `'y'` or `'n'` *plus* the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, which is added as a newline in the input buffer.

This newline is then read by the next `getline` call as an empty line.

There are a few solutions to this problem, for example using [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) after reading into `answer`. Or if you want only one-word inputs then you could use formatted input using `>>` for `sodaChoice` too, since it will by default skip leading white-space (like newlines).

Comment: @user202729 Yes formatted input with `>>` by default skips *leading* spaces. But the newline after the character is a *trailing* space which is not skipped by `std::getline`.

Answer (score 7):

Existing answers are correct in the case of the user behaving nicely and entering just a 'y' or an 'n' followed by a newline.

We can add a little safety with a modification to the .ignore() call by asking it to ignore all characters up to an including the next newline:

You will need to add this header include at the top of your translation unit:

```
#include <limits>
```

And you'll need to add this line before `cin >> answer`:

```
// consumes and ignores as many characters as necessary until a newline. 
// The newline is also consumed.
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Full program with test inputs here:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/996e77559590ad6d

Unfortunately, it's not unusual for Computer Science teachers to know nothing about computer science. Don't worry about this or let it put you off learning how to write software - it's just a symptom of the fact that good software engineers get paid a lot more than good teachers.

Here is some useful reference material: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to suggest something entirely the opposite of the other answers. Instead of using `cin.ignore` to skip any extra characters after the one you read, I think it's better to do all your reading with `getline()` and forget about `cin >> somevar` completely.

There are two reasons:

1. The formatted input you get with `cin >> somevar` ignores leading whitespace, including newlines. If the user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty line the program doesn't do anything, but still expects further input. This is not what the user of a CLI program expects! The usual expectation is that <kbd>Enter</kbd> completes the input, and an empty input should either cause the program to use a default value, or to complain about invalid input. With `cin >> somevar`, you can't do either.
2. Formatted input leaves any unmatched input in the buffer. In your example, reading a single character leaves at least the following newline, but the same happens with other kinds of input. Reading a number (with `int i; cin >> i;`) leaves anything after the number waiting for the next input operation, so entering `123 abc` will return `123`, and the `abc` will appear on the next input operation.

   The underlying cause of this is that by default, a command-line terminal is in a line-based mode. The program or the library functions don't see any input from the operating system until a complete line is entered. (`cin.ignore()` can of course help you deal with this, but not with the first point.)

Using `getline()` matches the underlying mechanic exactly, lets you deal with empty inputs (as well as telling the difference between a zero, and a non-number when reading to an `int`), and automatically deals with the trailing garbage. You'll have to convert the read string manually to whatever it is you actually want, though.

In your case, you could change the loop condition trivially to something like this:

```
string answer;
...
    getline(cin, answer);
} while (answer == "y" || answer == "Y");
```

If you need a number, you can use e.g. `int num = std::stoi(str)`.

---

<sup>(In C, the same happens if using `scanf()` for user input, and similarly, it's better to use `fgets()` and then parse the string with `sscanf()`, which gives the same options but deals with line-buffering. I'm not too familiar with C++, so I can't tell how to have the exact equivalent of `cin >> somevar` with a full line read by `getline()`.)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!  I really liked the other answers as well, but the curriculum we are following doesn't allow us to use things in our programs we haven't "learned" yet, so I was unable to use the cin.ignore unless I wanted to lose points.

Comment: @JKisa, argh. My deepest sympathies. I suppose you could work around that by manually reimplementing the equivalent of `cin.ignore`. Just write a loop that reads one character at a time, until it sees a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are taking input from the user of type `char` but every `Enter` key hit, it assigns the newline (`\n`)  to the variable `answer`.

You can ignore this by adding a line just after the input line

```
cin.ignore();
```

You may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25476169/1691223) for more details.