# how to access data by index

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

Im beginner to classes and I tried to make a simple library management system without file handling. So i used array instead. But when I try to show the input data by indexing(basically, entering number 2 after adding book to call the *showBook()*), it shows me random numbers and others are empty. I don't have any idea what is happening.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int p = 0;

void addBook();
void showBooks();

struct Library{
  string title[5], author[5];
  int isbn[5], price[5];
};

int main()
{
    while (true){
    cout << "\t\tLibrary Management Sytem\n";
    cout << "1. ADD BOOK.\n";
    cout << "2. SHOW BOOKS\n";
    cout << "Number: ";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    
    switch(x){
        case 1:
        addBook();
        break;
        case 2:
        showBooks();
        break;
        default:
        cout << "Invalid input.";
    }
    };
    
    return 0;
}
void addBook(){
    Library lib;
    cout << "Enter Book title: ";
    getline(cin, lib.title[p]);
    cin.ignore(232, '\n');
    cout << "Enter The Author: ";
    getline(cin, lib.author[p]);
    cout << "Enter ISBN: ";
    cin >> lib.isbn[p];
    cout << "Enter price: ";
    cin >> lib.price[p];
    p++;
}

void showBooks(){
    Library lib;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++){
        cout << "Book: " << lib.title[i] << endl;
    cout << "Author: " << lib.author[i] << endl;
    cout << "ISBN: " << lib.isbn[i] << endl;
    cout << "Price: " << lib.price[i];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Note: instead of a structure full of arrays, consider an array of structures. This is usually easier to manage.

Comment: Note rather than `p` being a global, make it a function parameter. Less potential for confusion. You should also give it a descriptive name. If all of your identifiers describe what they do or represent, code practically comments itself. Plus it's really easy to accidentally swap `p` and `q`, and if you have a `q` in the program, the compiler will probably allow it. Chaos ensues.

Comment: `cin.ignore(232, '\n');` kind of came out of nowhere. You might want to talk the purpose of the line over with [your Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). It might be necessary, but there's no way for me to know. It just looks weird.

Comment: @user4581301 to be honest, i dont have idea about that cin.ignore(). i just saw it here cause we also had the same prblem where it skips when asked to input book title. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475384/when-and-why-do-i-need-to-use-cin-ignore-in-c

Comment: To prevent the problem you're worried about the `ignore` needs to be after the last use of `>>` to read in data. `>>` stops as soon as it finds whitespace, newline is whitespace,  and leaves the whitespace in the stream. You want to ignore that extra whitespace, otherwise the next call to `getline` will instantly find the newline and exit without reading anything useful. Do not place the `ignore` before a `getline` because sooner or later you'll find a path through the code that hits the `ignore` without data you need ignored and wind up `ignore`ing data you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create a `Book` class that has one member each from `Library`.  Change `Library` to be a collection of `Book`, such as `std::vector` or array.  Parallel arrays (that you have in `Library`), can get out of sync.  Also, by have an array of struct (or class) your elements are next to each other in the memory cache.  Otherwise, `author[0]` will be placed after `title[4]`, and `author[0]` may not be in the data cache, so the data cache will need to be reloaded.

```
struct Book
{
  std::string title;
  std::string author;
  std::string isbn;
  int         price;
};

typedef std::vector<Book> Library;
```

You may want to overload `operator>>` to input a `Book` from the console.